# apache ant Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher

Tags: java, linux, ant

I'm trying to compile a tool which uses apache ant on linux

https://github.com/lindenb/jvarkit

When I tried to compile the tool , I get n error.

```
$ make vcffilterjs
```

this is what I get when I'm running the command

```
echo "Compiling htsjdk with ${JAVA_HOME} = /usr/lib/jvm/java/jre/"
Compiling htsjdk with /usr/lib/jvm/java/jre/ = /usr/lib/jvm/java/jre/
echo "Compiling htsjdk library for java. Requires  apache ANT. If it fails      here, it's a not a problem with jvarkit."
Compiling htsjdk library for java. Requires  apache ANT. If it fails here,  it's a not a problem with jvarkit.
echo "And ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac should be >=1.7"
And /usr/lib/jvm/java/jre//bin/javac should be >=1.7
(cd /home/jannahS/jvarkit/htsjdk-1.139 && ant )
Error: Could not find or load main class  org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
make: *** [/home/jannahS/jvarkit/htsjdk-1.139/dist/htsjdk-1.139.jar] Error 1
```

I have installed apache ant and tried to set ANT_HOME following google instruction

```
export ANT_HOME=apache-ant-1.9.6
ANT_OPTS="-Xms256M -Xmx512M"
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin
export ANT_HOME ANT_OPTS PAT
```

I also have set JAVA_HOME

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
```

When I run

ant --execdebug

```
exec "/usr/lib/jvm/java/jre//bin/java" -Xmx256M -classpath "apache-ant-  1.9.6/lib/ant-launcher.jar" -Dant.home="apache-ant-1.9.6" -Dant.library.dir="apache-ant-1.9.6/lib" org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -cp ""
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

I don't know what else to do to make things to work. I can't compile the tool that I want to use without  apache ant

Comment: `ANT_HOME` should have an absolute path.

Answer (score 16):

Use full path in ANT_HOME, eg:

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/lib/apache-ant-1.9.6
```

It dependes where it is exactly located

Comment: At first, i setup ANT_HOME wrong as "C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.10.8\bin",  it should be "C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.10.8" only, no "bin" in the end. After that, it works.

Comment: My ant home is /usr/share/ant on Redhat Linux 7.9.

Answer (score 7):

Could not find or load main class `org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher`

In mac this is due to some environment issue if you install the ant using brew command,

copy the lib folder from the ant and paste it into the bin folder

now run the command issue is resolved:-)

issue reason

ant is trying to get the `bin/lib/ant-launcher.jar` file from the invalid path

Comment: I was also having this issue (though I wasn't building the same project), with macOS installed via brew. Instead of copying over the lib folder, I set my ANT_HOME variable to: `/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.10.3/libexec` which allowed my build to work.

Comment: I like @tww0003's answer, but is there a way to set the variable independent of an ANT version?

Comment: In Mac, after running ```brew install ant```, I had to run ```brew link ant``` to fully link ant to system environment.

Running ```brew link --verbose --overwrite ant``` I get:

```Linking /usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.10.5... 
ln -s ../Cellar/ant/1.10.5/bin/ant ant
ln -s ../Cellar/ant/1.10.5/bin/antRun antRun
ln -s ../Cellar/ant/1.10.5/bin/antRun.pl antRun.pl
ln -s ../Cellar/ant/1.10.5/bin/complete-ant-cmd.pl complete-ant-cmd.pl
ln -s ../Cellar/ant/1.10.5/bin/runant.pl runant.pl
ln -s ../Cellar/ant/1.10.5/bin/runant.py runant.py
6 symlinks created``` Success!

Answer (score 1):

In Mac, after running `brew install ant`, I had to run `brew link ant` to fully link ant to system environment.

Running `brew link --verbose --overwrite ant` I get:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.10.5... 
ln -s ../Cellar/ant/1.10.5/bin/ant ant
ln -s ../Cellar/ant/1.10.5/bin/antRun antRun
ln -s ../Cellar/ant/1.10.5/bin/antRun.pl antRun.pl
ln -s ../Cellar/ant/1.10.5/bin/complete-ant-cmd.pl complete-ant-cmd.pl
ln -s ../Cellar/ant/1.10.5/bin/runant.pl runant.pl
ln -s ../Cellar/ant/1.10.5/bin/runant.py runant.py
6 symlinks created
```

And when running "ant" with no params from command-line:

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

Which is what I expect if testing outside the context of an existing ant project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run *"which ant"* >> to know if the ant_home set. If not please run below with your corresponding paths to set ant_home

export ANT_HOME =/ade_autofs/gd29_3rdparty/ANT_1.7.1_GENERIC.rdd/080925/ant
export PATH=/ade_autofs/gd29_3rdparty/ANT_1.7.1_GENERIC.rdd/080925/ant:${PATH}

> Try ant build. It should work without any error.

Answer (score 0):

**"I agreed with full path issue for the above issue, getting the same exception while folder has access problem"**

I have faced the same exception in Macbook. Checked all the configurations JAVA_HOME, ANT_HOME and org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher file in Ant related jars. Finally, found the issue, due to an access problem of the apache-ant folder. I have no admin access, so I moved my setup to the desktop.

Answer (score -1):

---

`$ make vcffilterjs` : Compiles OK, with any of these "Linux OS´s" :

Debian 8 Jessie, CentOS 7, Fedora 23, Ubuntu 15.10, PCLinuxOS 2015.

No "ANT_HOME" or "JAVA_HOME" settings required, by using the default installed 'ant' and openjdk.

? Which "Linux OS" are you using ?

---

[ant](/questions/tagged/ant)[jvarkit](/questions/tagged/jvarkit)

Comment: Linux 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 x86_64